# Excel VBA - Compare two columns side by side

Tags: vba, excel

So I have the following code that I use for comparing values in two columns, but it is based on if the value is in either column, NOT a side by side comparison.

Is there a way to easily modify the code to do a side by side comparison? (meaning I want it to check if cell A1=B1, A2=B2, A3=B3, etc)

```
Sub compare_cols()

    'Get the last row
    Dim Report As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet

    lastRow = Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        For j = 2 To lastRow
            If Report.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
                If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 2).Value, Report.Cells(i, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                    Report.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White background
                    Report.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Report.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                    Report.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'Now I use the same code for the second column, and just switch the column numbers.
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        For j = 2 To lastRow
            If Report.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
                If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 1).Value, Report.Cells(i, 2).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Report.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White background
                    Report.Cells(i, 2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Report.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                    Report.Cells(i, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use Conditional formatting?

Comment: @Scott Craner shoot I meant to mention in the OP that I want to do it in VBA even though I know it is quite simple via conditional formatting.

Comment: What you're looking for seems to be much simpler than the code you posted.  Have you tried something?  PS "I want to do it in VBA" while showing no effort yourself to do just that makes it sound like you fully expect us to do it for you.

Comment: @Scott Craner - although if I wanted to do this in Conditional Formatting would I simply just do a new rule then: IF(A1<>B1)? Format it to then highlight the cell

Comment: That is close `=$A1<>$B1`. The columns need to be absolute and the IF() is not needed.

Comment: @ScottCraner ahh there we go. Thanks